# The Leibniz - Turing Dilemma

Tags: artificial-intelligence, identity, sentience

[The Turing Test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test) is basically the idea that when (a) computer and a human can't be differentiated, that computer is an AI.

[Identity of Indiscernibles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles#:%7E:text=The%20identity%20of%20indiscernibles%20is,by%20y%20and%20vice%20versa.) boils down to if A is *indistinguishable* from B then A = B

Suppose now that AI is realized/actualized.
Since this AI can't be told apart from humans, it follows that AI = humans.

If so per *The Indiscernibility of Identicals* rule, a dilemma on our hands:

1. *AI is sentient* because *we're sentient*.
2. *We're not sentient* because *AI is not sentient*.

What are the implications of *The Leibniz-Turing Dilemma*?

Comment: Maybe that we can use it as a negative criteria for discernibility: if a specific behavior can be replicated by a computer, than it is not an "essential" trait of human intelligence.

Comment: The Turing test is just a minimal standard that a "human-like" AI should pass. And even if the AI passes something much stronger the dilemma will much depend on how exactly it was "realized". If we grow humans in a Petri dish few will have a problem with ascribing "sentience" to them. If the "realizing" of the AI is similarly opaque (it already is opaque even for commercial ANN today), there will be no dilemma either. The dilemma will only emerge if the realization is such that it gives us strong reasons to disbelieve the AI's "sentience". I have no idea why that would be the case.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, is not *thinking* an *essential feautre* of being human?

Comment: @Conifold, the *dilemma* arises if we give our nod of approval to *the identity of indiscernibles* and subsequently *the indiscernibility of identicals*.

Comment: The Turing Test involves a test to see if you can tell a human from a computer only by interacting through an interface. The identity of indiscernibles doesn't allow for such limited testing. If there is any possible way of detecting a difference, then it doesn't claim identity.

Comment: Obviously, Leibniz rule does not apply: AI are not human because there are many properties that differ from human being, despite intelligence.

Comment: It's funny how "AI" has become a name of some entity like "human", when originally it was just the name of a sub-field of computer science.

Comment: @DavidGudeman, interesting point. We could say that Leibniz's rules don't apply in the limited sense in which it is in he Turing Test.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I concur, but if we were to allow a more restrcited application of Leibniz's rule, we do have a dilemma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment you appended to the excellent answer by Paul Ross shows that you are missing an important point. You can make almost any pair of objects indistinguishable by imposing constraints on one's ability to distinguish them. If I expose only a square inch of my old Isuzu pick-up truck you might find it indistinguishable from a corresponding glimpse of a Rolls Royce- does that mean my truck is a Rolls Royce? Clearly not. The example might appear trivial, but it illustrates the principle- if AI seems indistinguishable from humans only in a limited sense, then you cannot assume that AI has all of the properties of humans. You therefore need to rephrase the question as follows: given that AI has a given subset of capabilities that are observably indistinguishable from those of humans, does that mean AI is sentient? To answer that question with any degree of confidence you would need to have an accepted theory of consciousness.

Comment: That's a good analogy. The question is what is the correct yardstick for AI-human comparison?

Comment: @AgentSmith Marco is right: the equality does not hold, because only one little property of both was considered. There is no generalization that holds from that. But, why even try to compare a piece of software to humans?

Answer (score 1):

The limitation here is that the identity of indiscernibles is a *metaphysical* principle, not a principle of any form of distinguishability.  A machine constructed from fabricated silicon wafers is distinct from a human who has been born and grown organically, and while you can construct a linguistic communication framework in which the two can produce identical behaviours, that doesn't mean you can apply the Leibniz principle to it.

Now, if you're asking about the question of *building an ontology*  e.g. for machine learning, then there is something interesting to ask about whether you might treat a person as essentially a very sophisticated form of AI agent.  But that works only in a particular context of sense - when they report a malfunction with their internal process, you send a doctor rather than an electrical engineer (at least, if you wanted to help!)

Comment: What *distinction* we zero in on matters then. However, Alan Turing's genius shines through ... we're to ensure that the playing has been leveled so to speak - no *physical* features will be revealed, only *mental processes* are *accessible* to the tester/examiner.

Comment: Mental processes are notoriously *not* accessible to external examination - we read them indirectly through their supervenience on the physical.  That's exactly why a system of physical symbol exchange is appealed to as an intermediary over which to conduct the test, and this invites the problem of engineering the context to favour a certain model of distinguishability.

Comment: True and hence the dilemma, oui?

Comment: But it doesn't seem to be a well structured "metaphysical dilemma" (in the force of the Leibniz principles) if the distinction at work can be pulled apart in multiple directions.  You don't have to say "humans aren't sentient" in order to think that there might be a plurality of competing, disagreeing sentience concepts under evaluation, and that no one of them takes metaphysical priority over the others.  And just as there might be a plurality of concepts, so too could feature a plurality of Turing tests emphasising the respective sentience notions.

Comment: I intelligo. I'm, let's just say, working within the *metaphysical limitations/boundaries* Alan Turing and Leibniz were.